# How to hide the display of Toast message, on long press of ToolBar item(icon) android?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-menu

Is there some way to hide the toast after long-press on the ToolBar item?

android ToolBar icons or image button on long press is displaying a toast.

Comment: what you mean to say? 

display toast and when clicked on toobar ishoul disapear or what?

Comment: Read question carefully. The question is obvious.Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok. My Problem is solved.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final View v = findViewById(R.id.action_settings);

            if (v != null) {
                v.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final View v = findViewById(R.id.action_search);

            if (v != null) {
                v.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

And you can have clickable items of `Toolbar` :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_search) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"action_search",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }else if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"action_settings",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: why should we use `Handler` to set the OnLongClickListener?